# iOS get RGB color of multiple selection on UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to know the exact RGB components of multiple selection on `UITableView` because I need to use it even for the single selection to replace the standard Gray.

[image]

How can I get it ? If I take the screenshot and use DigitalColor Meter app on Mac the result is different.

Comment: Use the digital color meter in utilities folder.

Comment: Yes I did, but according to the edit logs it wasn't there when I read it.

Comment: Maybe the `backgroundColor` of `selectedBackgroundView`

Comment: Already tried but doesn't work